# Subsetting in r - getting NULL when I use a variable

Tags: r

I'm trying to filter through a list of 100 lists with four columns of data to pull out individual columns and operate on them.

The columns are: Date/Time, Measurement 1, Measurement 2, Identity Variable

```
 filepull <- list of 100 lists    
column_name <- "foo"    
meanoflist <- NULL    
        for (i in 1:100) {
                      holder_variable<-filepull[[i]]
                      meanoflist[i]<-mean(na.omit(holder_variable$column_name))

                 }
```

holder_variable$"foo" gives me what I need, but holder_variable$column_name gives me NULL.  What gives?

Thx for the help!

Comment: use `holder_variable[,column_name]` or `holder_variable[[columnname]]`

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `$` operator, the input doesn't get evaluated; it will be used as-is. So, by using `holder_variable$column_name`, you are actually trying to get the column with the name `column_name`. If you want to get the value with the name stored in a variable, use `holder_variable[, column_name]` (assuming `holder_variable` is a data.frame, from instance).

Take a look at [this example](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame/data-frame-column-vector), to better understand the difference.